# How to disable primary key constraint programmatically?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with primary key in my MS SQL Server 2005 table. I would like to disable it. Now i get error:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Name'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table'.

I would like this error not to occur and to work with PRIMARY KEY like with normal column without constraint and than restore this constraint after doing my changes to it. How to disable this constraint?

Query I want to execute while PRIMARY KEY constraint is disable is complex and changes values in primary key column. In some points of this query it hits the situation when I have duplicate values in primary key column. But at the end of my query I have all values unique.

I do not know much about this constraint because i'm not a designer of this table. I have it's name, but I don't now if it's clustered and so on (what is config of this column).

Comment: Changing PK values: this sounds really really weird! How can you change values that are supposed to be used to implement relations between tables? Are you sure the solution you are trying to elaborate is THE solution to your problem?

Comment: I don't have any relations on this PK. I know that sounds weird and maybe it's so, but this is THE solution that I need to apply in this place.

Comment: If there are duplicates, then it's not a primary key anymore, so why add it back ever?  Have you considered a concatenated primary key that will allow you to keep the constraint?

Comment: As I said, at the end of my query I have NO duplicates.

Comment: I decided to mark duffymo answer as correct one, because he pointed out why my way of solving this was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relational tables without primary keys are a very bad thing.  Each row has to be unique in some way.  If none of the candidate keys are designated as primary, the whole row has to be unique.

I'm not sure why you have to drop a primary key constraint, but I would consider doing that without replacing it with one of the other candidate keys is a red flag that should be investigated.

Comment: You've pointed out why this solution is bad, so I decided to mark your answer as proper one. And further more I've asked another question about the solution that will do this job in right way I think:

Comment: One reason why you may want to drop the constraint is if you are performing table changes to a lot of data. We recently added two new columns to a table with 8 Mil records. It took 23hrs to add the columns. If we drop the constraints, it takes 12 min. Of course, we are talking about offline upgrade. If it is an online upgrade, it would be dangerous to drop the constraints.

Answer (score 20):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Name
```

To reenable it:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Name PRIMARY KEY /* CLUSTERED */ (pk_column)
```

Uncomment `CLUSTERED` if you want your `PRIMARY KEY` to be clustered (i. e. the table rows themselves are being ordered)

To figure out if the `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered on not, issue:

```
EXEC sp_help 'mytable'
```

and look in the `6th` resultset returned.

Comment: This seems to delete constraint. How to restore it?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know if I have a primary key CLUSTERED or not. So I can not restore it in this way.

Comment: The primary key is clustered by default - so if you didn't change it, it's clustered.

Comment: I can't guess it because I didn't designed this table.

Comment: Ok, but how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Call the procedure, take the resultset, parse the result

Comment: It looks like to be a messy solution for me.

Comment: And it sure is. Instead of doing it programmatically, you can figure out what the primary key is using Management Studio, it's a one time task.

Comment: No, it's not one time task bacause I will issue this command from my application for many tables. So I would like to do it fully programmatically. If it would be one time task I would be doing it in Management Studio, but it is not.

Comment: Figuring out whether the PRIMARY KEY is CLUSTERED on not is a one time task. Then you can drop and create the PRIMARY KEY programmatically.

Comment: And sure, dropping and creating the PRIMARY KEY is messy. You could possibly rewrite you query so that is does not violate the PRIMARY KEY, but since you didn't ask for it, here is the solution you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

To find out what the primary key is (assuming your table is dbo.T1):

```
select si.name as name,  
(case  when (si.status & 16) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as isclust,
si.keycnt as keycnt,
si.indid as indid
from sysindexes si
left join sysobjects so on so.id = si.id 
where  si.indid > 0 
and  si.indid < 255 
and so.xtype <> 'S'
and so.id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T1')
and (si.status & 2048) > 0
```

This will give you something like:

```
name                                   isclust     keycnt indid
---------------------------------------------------------------
PK_T1                                      1           2      1
```

Here you have your primary key name (PK_T1), whether it's clustered or not, number of fields in it (2) and index id (you'll need it later).

Next run the following:

```
select INDEX_COL('dbo.T1', 1, 1) --returns Field1
select INDEX_COL('dbo.T1', 1, 2) --returns Field2
```

This will give you the names of two fields from the index. First parameter is your table name, second is index id obtained earlier and the third one loops from 1 to keycnt (returned on the previous step).

Having this information you should be able to reconstruct the primary key as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Field1, Field2)
```

Update: This might not be as accurate as parsing sp_help result mentioned [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737152/how-to-disable-primary-key-constraint-programmatically/737165#737165) (you will miss the sort order and filegroup), but easier programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The below Worked for me(you must be db_owner to perform this action)

--Declare a variable to get the contraints on the table and assign to a variable

```
DECLARE @PK_CONST_NAME AS varchar(100)
SET @PK_CONST_NAME = (SELECT NAME FROM SYS.KEY_CONSTRAINTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) = '[TABLENAME]')
```

--Variables to store the queries

```
SET @DropAlterQuery = ''
SET @RecreateAlterQuery = ''
```

-- Contruct Query

```
SET @DropAlterQuery = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] DROP CONSTRAINT ',@PK_CONST_NAME)
```

-- Executing the query constructed for Droping the contraints

```
EXEC(@DropAlterQuery)
```

-- Alter Column Size (Now this statement works as contraints are dropped)

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME]
ALTER COLUMN BATCH_ID VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
```

-- Contruct Query

```
SET @RecreateAlterQuery = CONCAT(CONCAT('ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] ADD CONSTRAINT ',@PK_CONST_NAME), ' PRIMARY KEY (<<PRIMARY KEY COLUMN1>>, <<PRIMARY KEY COLUMN2>>, <<PRIMARY KEY COLUMN2>>... So on)')
```

-- Executing the query constructed for Recreate the dropped contraints

```
EXEC(@RecreateAlterQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not violate PKEY constraint. IMHO it's the best solution, you will avoid cost of rebuilding a PKEY and what if you can't (duplicate remaining) ?

OR

Read the schema to know how to rebuild the PKEY constraint then use previouly posted solution.

Comment: Rebuilding PKEY is not a cost for me, so I would like to go in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a better idea to `SELECT` your entire table into a temporary table, doing the transformation on the fly if possible, and then copying it back. And if you can't transform on the fly, it's a lot easier to add a simple integer row index as the primary key on the temporary table.